# How can I increase MySQL or MariaDB constraint name length?

Tags: mysql

I have a country table that has a column named `AdministrativeDivisionTypeId`. This column is a foreign key to `AdministrativeDivisionTypes`.

Based on a tool that creats this database from a given JSON automatically, this foreign key creation script is generated:

```
ALTER TABLE Countries
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Countries_AdministrativeDivisionTypeId_AdministrativeDivisionTypes_Id` FOREIGN KEY (`AdministrativeDivisionTypeId`) REFERENCES `AdministrativeDivisionTypes` (`Id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

However, I get this error:

> Error in query (1059): Identifier name 'FK_Countries_AdministrativeDivisionTypeId_AdministrativeDivisionTypes_Id' is too long

Is there a way for me to increase this length?

Comment: Why not just use a shorter name? e.g. `FK_Countries_AdministrativeDivisions`

Comment: *Is there a way for me to increase this length?* No, this is hardcoded restriction.

Comment: *Based on a tool that creats this database from a given JSON automatically, this foreign key creation script is generated* - formally this is a tool bug.

Comment: @Akina, I hate hardcoded restrictions in the age of huge spaces available. Things are not updating fast enough in MySQL.

Comment: @Akina, it's not. It's semantics. It is basically `table1_column1_table2_colum2` formula. It's very semantic.

Comment: @Dai, what if they have two relations? For example `Persons` and `Relations`. The `Relations` table has two foreign keys to `Persons`. Then what? Naming them `1` and `2`?

Comment: @Hasan There is no _SQL constraint-name Stasi_ out there that will arrest you for not following some imagined naming-convention for your FK. You can name it **anything you want**, even `this_is_not_an_fk` - so if you _really_ have to ask me that question that demonstrates you are experiencing a total failure of imagination.

Comment: *It's very semantic.* The tool does not check the object name length and produces synthactically incorrect SQL code. This is a bug. The tool should check the length and report this problem to the user with the recommendation to make the name shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Rename the Foreign Key with a shorter name. Because MySQL allows names with a maximum allowed length of 64 characters https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-length.html